# C++ shared+ptr use_count for nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have 2 `shared_ptr`s defined and assigned `nullptr`. In case 1, I'm using default constructor and in case 2, I used constructor with delete method.

```
shared_ptr<int> sptr2(nullptr);

cout << "sptr2 use_count: " << sptr2.use_count() << endl;

shared_ptr<int> sptr6(nullptr, default_delete<int>());

cout << "sptr6 use_count: " << sptr6.use_count() << endl;
```

The output is:

```
sptr2 use_count: 0
sptr6 use_count: 1
```

I cannot understand why sptr6 has use count of 1 when it does not have any valid pointer.

g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)

Comment: The C++11 implementation in the GCC 4 series wasn't complete. Even if a class or function existed, it might not have been fully implemented or contain bugs. I highly recommend you update to a later version of GCC.

Comment: By the way, `shared_ptr<int> sptr2(nullptr);` does technically isn't default construction, that would be `shared_ptr<int> sptr2;` The result should be the same, but you're not using the default constructor. At least according to [this `shared_ptr` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per `[util.smartptr.shared.const]` in C++11 & C++14 (I haven't checked C++17), the `shared_ptr` is "empty" if you pass no argument. Otherwise, the `shared_ptr` "owns `p`" even for the case that `p` is a `nullptr_t`.

When a deleter is provided this makes sense (you have to store the deleter somewhere, after all), but what the purpose of this is for the single-argument constructor I couldn't say.

I'm apparently not alone, because the C++11/C++14 specification for the actual functions (`[util.smartptr.shared]/1`) lists `constexpr shared_ptr(nullptr_t) : shared_ptr() { }`, which suggests this construction (but not the construction that provides a deleter) should result in an "empty" `shared_ptr`!

But this is in direct contradiction to the listed semantics (which specifically give `use_count == 1` as a post-condition for both of your examples), and would therefore appear to be a bug in the standard.

GCC has apparently chosen to side with the function specification (as has cppreference.com). At least your deleter should be a no-op in this case.

To *actually* use the default constructor, write this:

```
shared_ptr<int> sptr;
```

Comment: On the other hand, the C++11 specification have this constructor line specified: `constexpr shared_ptr(nullptr_t) : shared_ptr() { }`. So passing a `nullptr` should make the `shared_ptr` object be "empty" (§20.7.2.2.1)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Regarding §20.7.2.2.1, is that reference correct? It doesn't appear to have anything to do with shared_ptr?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: How's that now?

Comment: Nope wrong section by me. Sorry about that. But good and instructive answer, so +1 from me :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I've asked `std-discussion` to weigh in. They can either fix it in the standard or set me straight ;)

Comment: I don't quite follow you here. Which post-condition in the standard says that `shared_ptr(nullptr_t)` should create a non-empty pointer?

Comment: @ArneVogel: The only constructor documented in `20.8.2.2.1` as creating an "empty" pointer is the default constructor. Taking `nullptr_t` makes it fall under /3-7 (via conversion to `T*` - no other valid resolution is listed), no? At best the behaviour of a hypothetical `shared_ptr(nullptr_t)` is simply not given.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a misinterpretation IMO. Someprogrammerdude pointed out that there is an inline definition (delegating c'tor) of `shared_ptr(nullptr_t)` in the preceding section. This is sufficient because there is already an explanation of what the constructor that is delegated to does. It isn't even the only place in the standard where the behavior of a method is not explained in prose, and only the (trivial) definition of it is given, e.g. `basic_string()` is defined as delegating to `basic_string(Allocator())`.

Comment: @ArneVogel: Oh, you could be right - I missed that it's delegating. I think either you or SPD should write an answer tbh

Answer (score 4):

The reason of different behavior caused by the shared_ptr design. SharedPtr refer to "control object", and control object refers to "user object".

If you initialize shared_ptr with nullptr (sptr2), control object is not created. Constructor does nothing.

If you initialize shared_ptr with deleter (sptr6), control object is created to store deleter. So, if control object created, it has to have reference count 1.

Comment: PavloK The control object should be an implementation detail.

Comment: @Oliv But the deleter still needs to be stored, and which I think is a very good reason for this behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Mm that makes sense.

Comment: @all. I'm not sure that I completely understand what are you trying to say in context of my post. Anyway... Why you not surprised that control object remains alive while at least one weak_ptr refers to it. All shared_ptr objects finish their live-cycle, user object deleted, but if there week_ptr exists, then control_object remains.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Whatsoever the counter is stored on the control object. So it could theoreticaly have been set to zero. I believe that implementation of shared_ptr before c++14 when there were no share_ptr to array, where based on the assumption that count==0 implies that the control object can be destroyed if the weak count is null. They just did not want to force implementer to rework shared_ptr.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude On the other hand I am not able in 10 min to find an other solution that the one adopted by the standard. Personnaly, I found the concept of "pointer ownership" so weired that I have implemented shared_object. Such problem does not exist with it.

Comment: Are you saying that my explanation is wrong, or you saying that shared_ptr implementation is wrong? :) The question was "why", I answered. And I didn't mentioned C++ standard. PS. actually there were no question, but I believe that "I cannot understand" means "why" )

Comment: @PavloK No I am saying that in a perferct world, this should have been an implementation detail. Your answer is a demonstration of pragmatism. I upvote it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :) . And BTW. There is [use_count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) description. It says: Return value:
the number of shared_ptr instances managing the current object or ​0​ if there is no managed object. And per description of reset and swap functions, "managed object" is what I called "control object" (added this to my post).

Comment: Please. Disregard my previous sentences. "managed object"  is not what I called "control object". And it seems that use_count should return 0 in our case according to cppreference.com